# Jquery mousenter show hyperlink on hovered container

Tags: jquery, events, mouseevent

I have this Jquery snippet which on mouse hover shows hidden hyper links,  my problem that is a nested list and if I hover on a child the parent is going to be shown as well. How to show hyper links on actual hovered conatiner

```
 $("div.dd3-content, div.dd-action-handle")
            .mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('div.dd-action-handle a').show();
            })
            .mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('div.dd-action-handle a').hide();
            });
```

**HTML**

```
<ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="22">
        <button type="button" data-action="collapse">Collapse</button>
        <button type="button" data-action="expand" style="display: none;">Expand</button> 
        <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></div>
        <div class="dd3-content"><href="#" class="editable editable-click" data-url="/post" data-pk="22">some</href="#"></div>
        <div class="dd-action-handle">
            <a href="/admin/dashboard/get_menu_item/22" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" class="edit_menu" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a style="margin-left: 10px; display: none;" href="#" class="remove_menu"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="23"> <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></div><div class="dd3-content"><href="#" class="editable editable-click" data-url="/post" data-pk="23">Tutorials</href="#"></div><div class="dd-action-handle">
                    <a href="/admin/dashboard/get_menu_item/23" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" class="edit_menu" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a style="margin-left: 10px; display: none;" href="#" class="remove_menu"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/dSaVU/

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Can you please add your markup to the question?

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what you're trying to accomplish with that markup...

Comment: I just prepare jsfiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see, your problem comes from event propagation : when it's fired on child nodes, it also bubbles on parent elements. The solution is to block the propagation once it triggered once :

```
 $("div.dd3-content, div.dd-action-handle")
            .mouseenter(function(ev) {
                $(this).parent().find('div.dd-action-handle a').show();
                ev.stopPropagation();
            })
            .mouseleave(function(ev) {
                $(this).parent().find('div.dd-action-handle a').hide();
                ev.stopPropagation();
            });
```

**EDIT :**
Since you released your JSFiddle, I checked it. The following solves the problem "When hovering a parent, sub-childs are shown" which seems to be your problem (it just look-up for direct childNodes)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.dd3-content, div.dd-action-handle")
      .mouseenter(function() {        
           $(this).parent().children('div.dd-action-handle').children('a').show();
       })
       .mouseleave(function() {
           $(this).parent().children('div.dd-action-handle').children('a').hide();
       });
  });
```

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I've been trying your workaround is not working in my case

Comment: I checked your JS-Fiddle - thank you, it made it clearer - and from what I seen, your problem is rather "if I hover on a parent the child is going to be shown as well." (Because the other way worked fine for me)